# Unable to wake up app from background on Xiaomi devices till "Autostart" is enabled manually

Tags: android, android-service, android-broadcast, android-broadcastreceiver

On Xiaomi's MI devices, there is a feature of turning off/on "Autostart" in their security app. (In Security App->Permissions->AutoStart)

[image]

This means none of the broadcast receivers receive anything while the app is not running. So BOOT_COMPLETED, USER_PRESENT, CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE, etc... do not work. (They work for a while after the app is on foreground, but stop soon). They also stop working after the user swipes the app from Xiaomi's version of "recent apps"

**Even GCM fails to wake it up**

For messaging apps, this is a killer.

By default, apps like Whatsapp, Messenger, Flipkart etc... are enabled by default (Even if these apps are not pre-installed).

Most other apps have this disabled by default. eg. Slack is disabled by default.

Is there a way to get on this white-list by default?

Comment: Don't know how to get app whitelisted. You can ask users to enable auto-start on launch, if they are on Xiaomi phones.

Comment: i have the same issue. any solution yet?

Comment: @gautam Any update on this?

Comment: Anyone found the solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can actually disable the battery optiomisation for your app. It'll turn all off the optimisations for the app so it won't get killed.

```
boolean isIgnoringBatteryOptimizations = pm.isIgnoringBatteryOptimizations(getPackageName());
if(!isIgnoringBatteryOptimizations){
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName()));
    startActivityForResult(intent, MY_IGNORE_OPTIMIZATION_REQUEST);
}
```

Now check if the optimisation has been disabled for your app.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == MY_IGNORE_OPTIMIZATION_REQUEST) {
        PowerManager pm = (PowerManager)getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        boolean isIgnoringBatteryOptimizations = pm.isIgnoringBatteryOptimizations(getPackageName());
        if(isIgnoringBatteryOptimizations){
            // Ignoring battery optimization
        }else{
           // Not ignoring battery optimization
        }
    }
}
```